# Laravel function callback

Tags: php, laravel, function, callback

I need to find certain cues in a string and call functions with these cues

Example

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class ModulesController
{
    private $modules = [ ['name' => 'someFunction','maxNumber' => 50] ];
    public function checkFunctions($strings = NULL)
    {
     $moduleArrayId = array_search($strings ,array_column($this->modules, 'name');
     if($moduleArrayId !== FALSE)
         $this->$modules[$moduleArrayId]['name'];

    }

    public  function someFunction()
    {
       return "it works";
    }
}
```

And resource example

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\ModulesController;

class BlockController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
     $this->middleware('auth:members');
  }

  public function index(Request $request)
  {
     $string = "someFunction";
     $callBack = new ModulesController;
     var_dump($callBack->checkFunctions($string)); //Always its NULL
  }
}
```

I have to use this code like this.
If I can understand this, I will try to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function checkFunctions($strings = NULL)
{
    $moduleArrayId = array_search($strings ,array_column($this->modules, 'name'));
    if($moduleArrayId !== FALSE) {
        $method = $this->modules[$moduleArrayId]['name'];
        return $this->$method();
    }
}
```

Not sure how much you changed your code in order to post here, but I would suggest you to:

- Use better names.
- Do not instantiate/call directly a controller from other controller. Controllers should only be used to handle requests, everything else should be moved to a separate class.
- Modify the structure of `$modules` to an associative array, so you can check if the method is defined by index, instead of using array_search. This can make your code run much faster as the size of this structure grows.

Example:

```
private $modules = [
    'someFunction' => [
        'maxNumber' => 50
    ]
];

// and then to check if the method is defined:
if (isset($this->modules[$strings])) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed `)` in

```
$moduleArrayId = array_search($strings ,array_column($this->modules, 'name'));
```

That's why you are getting default value `NULL` all the time.

Comment: No, there is no connection.

Comment: you haven't returned any value